# DB entity in dropdown symfony2

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, drop-down-menu, doctrine

In a DB I have two tables such like this:

```
USER
================
ID, Name, idType
================
1 , Alex, 2
2 , Paul, 3
...

TYPES
=========
ID, Type
=========
1 , FirstType
2 , SecondType
3 , ThirdType
...
```

The fields 'idType' in USER table is referenced with 'ID' fields in TYPES table.

Using Symfony2 I need to create a new record in my USER table using a web form, so I need a dropdown box to set the field 'idType'.
In my src/Acme/MyBundle/Form/Type/UserType.php I'm able to create and show the dropdown box with the extracting record from my TYPES table:

```
$builder->add('idType', 'entity', array('class' => 'AcmeMyBundle:Types','property' => 'type',));
```

Anyway obviously I can't insert this value in my db becouse I need to show in the list the 'Type' field (who is a human readable string ) but I need to insert in the DB the referenced 'ID' field (integer).

Statically I would perform this operation such this:

```
$builder->add('idType', 'choice', array('choices'   => array('1' => 'FirstType', '2' => 'SecondType', '3' => 'ThirdType'), 'required'  => false));
```

Is possible to perform this operation? Using a Dropdown box I need to extract an entity from a DB, show a field of this entity, but select to insert another referenced field.
I read the documentation: http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html but this do not helped me.
Thanks.

Comment: "but select to insert another referenced field": do it in controller

Comment: How to do it? I know I can use form function in my controller, but the code to build my dropdown element would be the same I already used...